# wanting to replace schema value of a sql script by providing schema value 'sdg_cdr' through shell script, but getting error

Tags: postgresql-9.1

#!/bin/bash
schema_name_new=sdg_cdr
echo "Initial truncate of tables"
sed -i 's/"$schema_name"/"$schema_name_new"/g' delete.sql
psql -f delete.sql
echo "Tables truncate completed"

echo "start time"
date
echo "end time"
date

Comment: getting error:- psql:delete.sql:1: ERROR:  schema "schema_name_new" does not exist.

Comment: kindly provide a resolution in my query.